# Avoid duplication in Amazon DMS CDC/ Ongoing Replication task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, aws-dms

We are performing a DMS task CDC with ongoing replication From RDS Mysql to Redshift. The issue We are facing is some records are inserted to Target Redshift several times as a duplicate even we had a primary key.
Is there a best practice to avoid duplicate rows while running CDC Task on AWS DMS and as a Target Redshift?

(p.s we set primary and foreign keys but still, duplication occurs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift doesn't enforce uniqueness - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Defining_constraints.html
This is due to the nature of being a clustered data warehouse solution.

You will need to have an UPSERT process that explicitly deletes the previous rows for each PK and then insert the new row.  An INSERT only process will create duplicates in Redshift.  I believe that DMS has an option to do this but I don't have the docs in front of me ATM.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Yes, I am aware of primary key issues. I was looking for these DMS option docs, I tried aws dms official docs but there did not mention about this option

Comment: So I'm not an expert on DMS and in general advise away from it.  Like a lot of AWS high-end services it is an 80% solution with a number of deficiencies that trip people up.  I do know that the PKs between mySQL and RS need to match exactly for DMS to work correctly.  I think there is a switch to make it do an UPSERT process vs. INSERT but it may not be automatic when you select RS as the destination.  (be sure it is RS not postgres)  I'd look at the duplicates and see what differences these rows have, if any.  Could provide a clue as to the cause.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will look into this primary key and rows differences

Comment: @AzizSirojiddinov did you find solution to your issue? i am in same situation. thanks!